# Stretch imshow X axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm plotting a colormap with imshow, but I can't get the figure to stretch horizontally !

the code:

```
ylabels = ['0:00', '03:00', '06:00', '09:00', '12:00', '15:00', '18:00', '21:00']

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(27, 7))

cax1 = ax.imshow(df7, origin='lower', cmap='viridis', interpolation='none', aspect=4)
ax.set_xticklabels(label, fontsize = 12)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(df7.columns)))

major_ticks = np.arange(0, 24, 3)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_yticklabels(ylabels, fontsize = 12)


plt.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 12
plt.rcParams['ytick.labelsize'] = 12
fig.autofmt_xdate()



plt.colorbar(cax1,fraction=0.046, pad=0.04)




fig.suptitle('November 2016 Normalized Pressure Data $[mbar]$',fontsize=15)
fig.tight_layout(pad = 1)

plt.show()

fig.savefig('Pressure.png', dpi=300)
```

I've tried to use "aspect" when calling imshow but still the result is square pixels:

[image]

How can I stretch the X axis to fill the whole figure size ?

Thank you !

EDIT:

I've tried `aspect='auto'` and `aspect=0.25` but still the same result !

EDIT #2:

I removed the `ax.set_aspect(0.5)` and `tight_layout` duplicate, but still the figure is not filling the whole space of the picture size

Answer (score 3):

The keyword argument `aspect` sets the aspect of the image. From [the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow):

> **aspect** : [‘auto’ | ‘equal’ | scalar], optional, default: None
>     If *‘auto’*, changes the image aspect ratio to match that of the axes.
>   If *‘equal’*, and extent is None, changes the axes aspect ratio to match that of the image. If extent is not None, the axes aspect ratio is changed to match that of the extent.
>   If *None*, default to rc image.aspect value.

So the idea would be to use **`aspect='auto'`** instead of `aspect=4`.

You can of course also use a numeric value to set the aspect manually. However for a strech in X direction, the aspect needs to be smaller than 1, i.e. `aspect=0.25`

Comment: I've tried it as well (aspect='auto' and aspect=0.25) , but it doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: "It doesn't seem to work" is not a sufficient problem description. If you are talking about your code from the question, then you would of course need to remove the line `ax.set_aspect(0.5)`, use the same argument as in imshow, or remove the imshow argument and only use `ax.set_aspect`. Using every command only once makes it easier to debug the code, so having `tight_layout` in there twice is probably also not a good idea.

Comment: maybe you need to better explain what you actually mean by "not filling the whole space of the picture size".